# cin gives garbage if the size is smaller than the receiver array

Tags: c++, c++11

```
uint8_t data[252];
cout << "> " << flush;
cin >> data;
cin.clear();
```

If the user writes less than 252 chars, the data is padded with some garbage values.

- How can I prevent that?

Comment: Use `uint8_t data[252]{};` to pre-zero out the array?

Comment: perfect.. don't know how I could have missed that.. Thank you!

Comment: Also, consider reading into `std::string` instead.

Comment: Understood, it's just for testing, it'll be binary data later, not string. Thx

Comment: `std::string` exists for storing binary data...

Comment: ok, I'll need to check more, don't wanna deal with EOL or any other special character automatically added just because it's a string.

Comment: It doesn't. It leaves the existing garbage in the array undisturbed beyond the part it writes to.

Comment: An `std::string` is just a sequence of chars with a length. In fact, it's almost the same thing as `std::vector<char>`. It will store whatever it is told to store and nothing more.

Comment: Using `cin >>` for binary data is going to end in tears.  `cin` isn't opened in binary mode, and `>>` might not stop until it blows past the end of the buffer.

Comment: As I said, that's just for testing manually, in the end the user input will disappear ;)

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you don’t need that `flush` after the prompt. Reading from `std::cin` does that for you.

Comment: Understood, I saw that in an example and just kept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize your array to set the value of all index 0 and that way you won’t be getting garbage values.

`uint8_t data[252]{};`